# Gnome terminal keeps crashing on Ubuntu 22.04 where to find log?

Tags: logging, terminal, crash, gnome-terminal, rclone

All Gnome terminals keeps crashing randomly on Ubuntu 22.04, all scripts running on them crushed.
Did sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade but the problem persists
I would like to know where to find log?
This sometimes occurred when I upload files heavily using rclone through terminal but still not sure if this is the cause of it
Also, I notice that bandwidth also dropped before the crash
Any clue?
Or is there any more stable terminal I should use?
Googled hard but still can't find any info related to this

Comment: In the meantime, I'm using `xfce4-terminal` and it's been great. All of my bash profiles are still accessible. It's like nothing changed.